# Show selected item in search field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

On my website (written in React) I create a search field (using HTML tag input).
At the moment I have:

1. The user clicks on the field;
2. Enter one character;
3. Options that are in the database appear under the field

But at the moment the user cannot click on one of the proposed options. Therefore, what I would like to add:

1. The user clicks on one of the proposed options
2. The selected option is displayed in the input field, where the user entered the characters to search

   ```
   const mockData = [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: 'qwert',
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    name: 'ertyu',
   },
   ];
   ```

Component with field

```
export function Search() {
 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
 return (

   <div>
     <SearchIcon />

     <Form.Label htmlFor="title">
       Event
       <Form.Input
         placeholder="Search"
         onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
         value={query}
       />
     </Form.Label>
     {mockData.length &&
       mockData
         .filter((title) => {
           if (query === '') {
             return '';
           }
           if (title.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
             return title;
           }
         })
         .map((title) => (
           <div className="card" key={title.id}>
             <h3>{title.name}</h3>
           </div>
         ))}
   </div>
)}
```